# Checkbox array with string

Tags: vb6

I need help on how to use checkbox array , if checkbox is checked the value will be:

```
check1(0) = OK ,check1(1) = X,check1(2) = [X],check1(3) = NP
a=iif(check1(0).Value = vbchecked,"OK")
```

**Getting error:**

```
"Error sub or function not defined"
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `iif` and not `if`. See help. `If check1(0).Value = vbchecked then A = "OK"`.

Comment: I have 4 checkboxes if I check(0) then the value will be ok and if i check(1) the value will X.

Comment: Your `IIf` is missing an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how the line of code you presented would generate the error `sub or function not defined`.  Rather, you should have received the error`Argument not optional`.  The syntax for this line should have been like this:

```
a = IIf(Check1(0).Value = vbChecked, "OK", "")
```

If I understand your requirements, you COULD use `IIf` like this:

```
a = IIf(Check1(0).Value = vbChecked, "OK", IIf(Check1(1).Value = vbChecked, "X", IIf(Check1(2).Value = vbChecked, "[X]", IIf(Check1(3).Value = vbChecked, "NP", ""))))
```

However, I would not recommend this approach.  Instead, I would structure the code like this:

```
If Check1(0).Value = vbChecked Then
   a = "OK"
ElseIf Check1(1).Value = vbChecked Then
   a = "X"
ElseIf Check1(2).Value = vbChecked Then
   a = "[X]"
ElseIf Check1(3).Value = vbChecked Then
   a = "NP"
Else
   a = ""
End If
```

Yes, there is a little more code but the code is easier to read and easier to maintain.